# Error when running flutter after upgrade from flutter v1 (1.22.5) to flutter v2 (2.10.4)

Tags: flutter

i cant running to android device or ios simulator after proceed upgrade flutter from version 1 to 2, i already do flutter pub get to all module and pubspec.yaml (before that i already flutter clean and invalidate cache and restart)

when i tried to running the code, it will be like error like this:

```
Launching lib/launcher/main-dev.dart on ASUS I001DE in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevelopmentDebug'...
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:38:8: Error: Type 'SingletonBind' not found.
  List<SingletonBind> get instanciatedSingletons =>
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:43:12: Error: Type 'SingletonBind' not found.
      List<SingletonBind<Object>> singletons, Injector injector) {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:43:12: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
      List<SingletonBind<Object>> singletons, Injector injector) {
           ^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/models/bind.dart:4:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'Bind' is missing implementations for these members:
 - BindContract.cast
 - BindContract.copyWith
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class Bind<T extends Object> extends BindContract<T> {
      ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart:53:19: Context: 'BindContract.cast' is defined here.
  BindContract<E> cast<E extends Object>();
                  ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart:42:19: Context: 'BindContract.copyWith' is defined here.
  BindContract<T> copyWith({
                  ^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/models/bind.dart:46:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'AsyncBind' is missing implementations for these members:
 - BindContract.cast
 - BindContract.copyWith
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class AsyncBind<T extends Object> extends Bind<Future<T>>
      ^^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart:53:19: Context: 'BindContract.cast' is defined here.
  BindContract<E> cast<E extends Object>();
                  ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart:42:19: Context: 'BindContract.copyWith' is defined here.
  BindContract<T> copyWith({
                  ^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/models/bind.dart:68:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'BindInject' is missing implementations for these members:
 - BindContract.cast
 - BindContract.copyWith
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class BindInject<T extends Object> extends Bind<T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart:53:19: Context: 'BindContract.cast' is defined here.
  BindContract<E> cast<E extends Object>();
                  ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart:42:19: Context: 'BindContract.copyWith' is defined here.
  BindContract<T> copyWith({
                  ^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:25:6: Error: The return type of the method 'WidgetModule.getBind' is 'T?', which does not match the return type, 'BindEntry<T>?', of the overridden method, 'BindContextImpl.getBind'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
Change to a subtype of 'BindEntry<T>?'.
  T? getBind<T extends Object>(Injector injector) {
     ^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_core-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind_context.dart:48:17: Context: This is the overridden method ('getBind').
  BindEntry<T>? getBind<T extends Object>(Injector injector) {
                ^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/flutter_modular.dart:156:8: Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'BindEntry<GetArguments>'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
 - 'GetArguments' is from 'package:flutter_modular/src/domain/usecases/get_arguments.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/domain/usecases/get_arguments.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'call'.
      .call()
       ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/flutter_modular.dart:191:18: Error: The argument type 'BindEntry<ModularRouterDelegate>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ModularRouterDelegate'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
 - 'ModularRouterDelegate' is from 'package:flutter_modular/src/presenter/navigation/modular_router_delegate.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/navigation/modular_router_delegate.dart').
        injector.get<ModularRouterDelegate>(), navigatorKey);
                 ^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/modular_base.dart:178:7: Error: The method 'setDisposeResolver' isn't defined for the class 'ModularBase'.
 - 'ModularBase' is from 'package:flutter_modular/src/presenter/modular_base.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/modular_base.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setDisposeResolver'.
      setDisposeResolver(disposeBindFunction);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:26:24: Error: A value of type 'BindEntry<T>?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'T?'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
    return _fakeModule.getBind<T>(injector);
                       ^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:43:12: Error: 'SingletonBind' isn't a type.
      List<SingletonBind<Object>> singletons, Injector injector) {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:101:32: Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'BindEntry<BindModule>'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
 - 'BindModule' is from 'package:flutter_modular/src/domain/usecases/bind_module.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/domain/usecases/bind_module.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'call'.
    injector.get<BindModule>().call(widget.module);
                               ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/presenter/widgets/widget_module.dart:112:34: Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'BindEntry<UnbindModule>'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
 - 'UnbindModule' is from 'package:flutter_modular/src/domain/usecases/unbind_module.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/domain/usecases/unbind_module.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'call'.
    injector.get<UnbindModule>().call<T>();
                                 ^^^^
../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_modular-4.5.1+1/lib/src/infra/services/bind_service_impl.dart:21:20: Error: The argument type 'BindEntry<T>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.
 - 'BindEntry' is from 'package:modular_interfaces/src/di/bind.dart' ('../../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modular_interfaces-2.0.0/lib/src/di/bind.dart').
      return right(result);
                   ^

         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of flutter_webview_plugin will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/androidx-migration for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/dev3sinarmas/tools/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/dev3sinarmas/tools/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevelopmentDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is my flutter doctor:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry i already found it, just update dependency flutter modular to the lastest